# Allowing user to choose an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, user-input

I am trying to sharpen my python programming skills by coding solutions to basic physics problems.

The problem states that a spaceship is traveling a distance x at a velocity v towards a destination from Earth. I am to find the time elapsed by a stationary observer on Earth and the time elapsed by a passenger aboard the spaceship. Rather than assigning values to x and v, I am to allow the user to input values for x and v. But, I would like to allow the user to choose how they would like to input their data. For example, the user could put v = some number in meters/sec or the user could put v = a*c where 0 ≤ a ≤ 1 and c = speed of light; I would like to let the user decide which input is preferred.

I understand how to ask the user to input a value.
ex: 
    x = float(input("What distance has the spaceship traveled:  "))

But how can I let the user decide which v they would like to input?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest to try code formatting to make it easier for readers to understand the question and why not input also the "velocity input strategy choice" into a variable, and then subsequently offer a matching velocity input prompt based on that value? Also some best effort working sample code would be great.

Comment: with an if statement. You could give the user 2 choices. Choice 1, use the preset value a*c as v. choice 2, prompt the user to input v. Or you could parse the data.

Comment: If else statement block https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possiblility 1 : Two questions

`input(...)` returns a string. Therefore you can ask the user which input style is preferred, à la

```
Which input format is preferred? ([a]bsolute/[f]raction of c) >
```

Then use an `if`/`else` block to test whether the user has entered `a` or `f`.

Subsequently, ask another question

```
Enter the desired speed (number) >
```

and convert the input to float just like you have done above (`float(input(...))`)

## Possibility 2

You can ask a question like

```
Enter spaceship speed:
```

and test if the last character which is entered by the user is a `c`. Then you use the number as fraction of light speed. Else, you use the number as absolute speed.

To get the last character of a string, use

```
s = 'abc'
lastcharacter = s[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I especially like the second method, but I really appreciate showing you multiple methods.